# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Tags: scala

In the Scala application, I am facing `java.lang.ClassCastException` anyone known how to cast a string to float?

Here is my code:

```
deviceVal.asInstanceOf[String].toFloat
```

Comment: Are you sure that `deviceVal` is a String? Could you remove `toFloat`, and just try casting it to String, to see it that's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't **cast** `String` to `Float` and vice versa. They have incompatible runtime classes. `1.5F.asInstanceOf[String]` and
`"1.5F".asInstanceOf[Float]` fail with `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

You can transform `String` to `Float` and vice versa in the following way

```
assert("1.5".toFloat == 1.5F)
assert("1.5F".toFloat == 1.5F)
assert(1.5F.toString == "1.5")
```

If a `String` can't be parsed into a `Float` you'll get `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Most probably `java.lang.ClassCastException` means that problem is with `deviceVal.asInstanceOf[String]`. Maybe `deviceVal` is not a `String` and can't be casted to `String`. You can transform `deviceVal` (whatever it is) to a `String` like `deviceVal.toString`.